# Python for each but stop after n elements

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that can be anywhere from 0 to 100 elements long. I want to look through the first three elements only, and I don't want to throw an error if there are less than three elements in the list. How do I do this cleanly in python?

psuedocode:

```
for element in my_list (max of 3):
    do_stuff(element)
```

EDIT: This code works but feels very unclean. I feel like python has a better way to do this:

```
counter = 0
while counter < 3:
    if counter >= len(my_list):
        break

    do_stuff(my_list[counter])
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slice the list:

```
for element in my_list[:3]:
    do_stuff(element)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings) says that there won't be any errors if the list doesn't have elements on those indices, thus you can safely use that on lists containing less than 3 elements. List slicing returns a new list.

The *slightly* more efficient way (for big slices) would be to use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
for element in islice(my_list, 0, 3): # or islice(my_list, 3)
    do_stuff(element)
```

Comment: More efficient? It is only 3 elements!

Comment: I'm not convinced that it is actually _more_ efficient... slicing a list is lightning fast as far as python operations are concerned, and in my experience, `listiter.__next__` operates faster than `__next__` on most other objects.  The memory overhead for a list of 3 elements is pretty minimal as well.  I think the real reason to use `islice` is to support iterables and not just sequence objects.

Comment: I think its so people can write stuff like `slice = islice(fancy_salami, 0, 3); print("Who wants the {}?".format(next(slice))`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- Yes, that's gotta be it.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `itertools.islice`:

```
for element in itertools.islice(my_list, 0, 3):
    do_stuff(element)
```

Of course, if it actually *is* a list, then you could just use a regular slice:

```
for element in my_list[:3]:
    do_stuff(element)
```

Regular slices on normal sequences are "forgiving" in that if you ask for more elements than are there, no exception will be raised.

Answer (score 3):

```
for element in my_list[:3]:
    do_stuff(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

@mhawke's answer is perfect if it's actually a `list` or something else that supports the slice interface.

For a more general iterable type, try the ever-handy [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for ii, element in enumerate(my_list):
    if ii>=3:
        break
    do_stuff(element)
```